# How to set the font case of a listbox item in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a `ListBox` in a WPF Window.
Based on the selected item of a `ComboBox`, the `ListBox` items are retrieved from database and bound as the ListBox's `ItemSource`. 
I want to change the case of the `ListBox` items, i.e., when i bind all the items are in uppercase. I want to change the case to capitalize only the starting letter of a word.

Answer (score 1):

You need a converter to achieve this behavior.

```
public class CaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        TextInfo textInfo = culture.TextInfo;
        return  textInfo.ToTitleCase(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();;
    }
}
```

Add this as resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CaseConverter x:Key="MyCaseConverter"></local:CaseConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use it in XAML as

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource MyCaseConverter}}"/>
```