# Convert the CharacterCasing of a ListBoxItem to UpperCase

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have read many articles on web regarding my problem, but everywhere I got the same answer : Use a converter.

One of them can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802020/how-to-set-the-font-case-of-a-listbox-item-in-wpf).

It's OK to use converter if you have less than 5 listboxes in your application.

Let's say I have 100 listboxes in a WPF application. Then I would like to apply characterCasing to a style which is used by those listboxes. In this case I would probably need a way that does not use Converter.

I think I may get this by using an attached property. I am not sure if I can use attached proerties in styles. If I can use those, then I would create an attached Property. But I don't know when to set or how to set the characterCasing of a ListBoxItem.

**Update:**

ListBox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ParentMenuItems}"          
         DisplayMemberPath="MenuItemName" />
```

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border Name="Border" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3" >
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushOrangeSelector}"/>
                        <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BitmapEffect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="2" Brush="#FFFF6A00"  />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>-->
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

**Update2:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource toUpperCaseConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Update3:**

```
public partial class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.MenuItems1 = new HashSet<MenuItem>();
    }

    public int MenuItemID { get; set; }
    public string MenuItemName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems1 { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem MenuItem1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Update4:**

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border Name="Border" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Converter={StaticResource toUpperCaseConverter}}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushOrangeSelector}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Orange" BlurRadius="10" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: by casing you mean capital letter at the beginning of each line ?

Comment: @eranotzap No, not just the first character. I mean all the letters to be capital.

Comment: i'm guessing you don't want a converter because you don't know what text would be bound to in the ItemTemplate ?

Comment: @eranotzap exactly. That's the point.

Comment: no necessarily i answered to quick ... please post one of your listbox's and what they are bound to as ItemsSource and i'll give you the best solution , if converters won't be the best solution we can easily do this with an attachedproperty bound to the Text property
of all TextBlock's with in the ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: show me a listbox , with an itemtemplate and an ItemsContainerStyle if exists

Comment: @eranotzap I dont have a listbox with ItemContainerStyle. But I have all of them with ItemTemplate applied to its style. I have updated my question.

Comment: i don't see an ItemTemplate .
and i see you do have a style from ListBoxItem ,that's what i men't as ItemsContainerStyle , you can use it explicitly by setting it in the listbox , or implicitly simply by create a style for ListBoxItem (type) key ,  so what doe's that string you wanna capitalize come from ? what the $#@^ is it bound to?

Comment: @eranotzap Sorry, I did not define any ItemTemplate. So, every ListBox will have thier default ItemTemplates.

Comment: well you can create an attached property and put it in the listboxitem's style via setter bind it to the content property of listboxitem and capitalize it there . OR you can use a converter on the ContentPresenter like i tried below , i belie it would also work.

Comment: @eranotzap thanks. Let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing to do is create a converter
(this was not written in VS so keep notice that it's just a sample

```
  public class ToUpperCaseConverter : IValueConverter 
  {
     ///
  }


  <Border Name="Border" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3" >
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=MenuItemName,Converter={StaticResource uppercaseConverter}" />
  </Border>
```

Edit :  Try This :

```
 <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Converter={StaticResource toUpperCaseConverter}}" />
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: No, it does not work, gives me an error saying that Object Reference not set to an instance of the object and its quite understandable as RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem will look for a parent of ListBox of type ListBoxItem and it cannot find one.

Comment: It's Parent at some level is a ListBoxItem , did you run it or did you just see the xaml exception ?

Comment: I see the Compile-time error but Visual-Studio allows me to run the project. I get namespaces instead of actual data in output. Just think about this : How can a ListBoxItem become parent of ListBox?

Comment: @Vishal the DataTemplate replaces the ContentPresenter in ListBoxItem (control) Template.  

and ListBox contains ListBoxItems .

Comment: Oops! I was defining an ItemTemplate for ListBox. Any way I Have tried that and still I get namespaces instead of actual data. To see how I have done it please check Update4 in my question. There I did not use a dataTemplate as it gives me error. The error is Property Child does not support values of type DataTemplate.

Comment: You are suppose to define it in a ListBox , that's ok .
The ListBox generates ListBoxItem's via it's ItemContainerGenrator.
It sets the ItemTemplate as each one of ListBoxItem's ContentTemplate.

Start a chat and explain the entire issue to me , i feel invested :) 
let's find a better way to do what you are trying to achive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59897/discussion-between-vishal-and-eran-otzap).

Comment: @Vishal i can't seem to enter any thing in the chat , we will do this tommrow